# URL is duplicated in htaccess rewrite URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm kinda new with htaccess rewrite rules and I'm stuck. I made this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/?$ /single-product.php?product_name=$1 [NC,NS]
```

because I want to rewrite a URL like `site.com/products/product1` to `site.com/single-product.php?product_name=product1`.

The problem is when I try to access `site.com/products/product1` in the browser, the URL becomes `site.com/products/products/product1`. And if I refresh the browser, it becomes `site.com/products/products/products/products/product1`.

For full reference, this is my full `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/?$ /single-product.php?product_name=$1 [NC,NS]
```

What do I need to do to prevent this from happening?

EDIT:
I tested this on Firefox (I was previously testing in Chrome) and got a different result. I tried searching the same URL, `site.com/products/product1`, on Firefox and the result is `site.com/products/product1/products/product1/`

Comment: @anubhava already did. I also tried testing in a new incognito window in Chrome but still no luck :/

Comment: @anubhava I don't see any 30X / 40X redirects here

Comment: @anubhava I just double checked, there's really no redirects here. Isn't this something related to my server settings?

Comment: No. Without a redirect, browser cannot just add `/products` in URL everytime

Comment: @anubhava I see. I found something interesting. If I try to search site.com/products/products/products/products/products/product1, the URL becomes site.com/products/products/products/products/products/products/products/products/products/products/product1 --- 10 'products'. It seems that it doubles the 'products' word in the URL but still, I see no status 301 in the network tab

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# Prevent parsing other rules after that (L flag)
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/?$ /single-product.php?product_name=$1 [NC,NS,L]
```

or

```
# Prevent matching paths with another slash after products
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]*)/?$ /single-product.php?product_name=$1 [NC,NS,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. Your second suggestion quite worked a bit. So when I tried to search for site.com/products/product1, it still became site.com/products/products/product1. But when I refreshed it after that, it didn't multiply the number of 'products' in the URL anymore

Comment: Then easy way to solve it would be to use this `RewriteRule ^products/(?!products)(.*)/?$ /single-product.php?product_name=$1 [NC,NS,L]` although it's not the perfect solution.